# Error while sending SMS

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm writing code for sending SMS, but sending the SMS is failing. Additionally, sometimes my code has a crossed line and this warning: "The method sendTextMessage(String, String, String, PendingIntent, PendingIntent) from the type SmsManager is deprecated"

```
class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button bSend;
    EditText Mobile, msg;
    String mob, s_msg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        init();
        bSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSendSMS);
        Mobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMobile);
        mob = Mobile.getText().toString();
        msg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMsg);
        s_msg = msg.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(mob, null, s_msg, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a deprecation message because you've imported the wrong SmsManager Class.
Remove `android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager` and import `android.telephony.SmsManager`

Also, please make sure you've given the permission to send messages

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```